# Check if a Button is the default enter "Accept Button" of a form to draw a thicker border

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I wrote the paint event of all buttons of my form and in doing so, lost the thick border that appears for the AcceptButton of the Form that is triggered on Enter press.

Is there a way to know if a given button is set as its form's AcceptButton to draw accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is. How do you usually check whether a property is set to a certain value?

```vb
If myButton Is AcceptButton Then
```

That said, you most likely should not be handling the `Paint` event of every `Button`. You probably ought to create a custom class that inherits `Button` and overrides `OnPaint`, so the functionality is encapsulated. You can then do this inside that class:

```vb
If FindForm()?.AcceptButton Is Me Then
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks you again @jmcilhinney